# javascript api simplified

Tags: javascript, api, document-ready

Was using fourquare api to get venue, had previously had a clickable list written out from api but cut it down to just one venue name written to screen.  Then decided it'd be best to just send it over to php.  So when I did what I thought was logical cutting of the code, it stopped working completely.

My program has this, working:

```
$(document).ready(function doEverything(element) {
    $.getJSON("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=" + lat + "," + lng + "&client_id=L2VWBKPOW45D5X3FJ3P4MJB5TGVJ4ST2J005RIVAFIWG44ND%20&client_secret=ZKDAOLHASCA31VUOGMBTAS3RFYUOMXL4IFFYPRURIDQA3QMA%20&v=20111107", function(data) {
        one = data.response.venues[0].name;
        var list = [];
        list[0] = [one];

        function Make() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.style.margin = "-435px 100px 0px 110px";
                div.innerHTML = list[i];
                !
                function() {
                    var index = 0;
                    div.onclick = function() {
                        doSomething(this);
                    };
                }();
                document.body.appendChild(div);
            }
        }

        function doSomething(element) {
            var value = element.innerHTML;
            switch (value) {
            case one:
                break;
            }
        }
        Make();
    });
});
```

Then I decided I wanted to pass a variable over to php using this:

```
theVar = 10; //just to make things simple.
urlString = "cookiestesttwo.php?var=" +theVar;
window.location = urlString;
```

So I tried to simplify my api code to this, and it stopped working:

```
$(document).ready() {
    $.getJSON("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=" + lat + "," + lng + "&client_id=L2VWBKPOW45D5X3FJ3P4MJB5TGVJ4ST2J005RIVAFIWG44ND%20&client_secret=ZKDAOLHASCA31VUOGMBTAS3RFYUOMXL4IFFYPRURIDQA3QMA%20&v=20111107", function(data) {
        one = data.response.venues[0].name;
        document.write(one)
        theVar = one
        urlString = "cookiestesttwo.php?var=" + theVar;
        window.location = urlString;)
    };
};​
```

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "it stopped working"?

Comment: Did you bother watching your browser's Javascript console for any errors? Does your one version, where you hardcode in `10` for `theVar`, work? Also, why are you using `document.write` in the `$.getJSON`?

Comment: the errors are HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request and unknown property 'box-sizing'.

Comment: Please learn how to format your code (inside SO and outside).

Comment: While formatting your code (indentation) your second snippet is malformed. is the `}` and `)` being reversed a typo? or is this in your code? also `$(document).ready() {` is not proper syntax and **does** throw errors.

Comment: Why do you mix plain DOM code with jQuery?

Comment: @ThiefMaster I presume A) they don't know how to use XHR so the jQuery is just for ajax + DOMContentReady (redundant, yes, but maybe the OP thinks he needs it). and B) The rest of the code appears like a copy-paste job.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem might be that you use `document.write()` when the DOM is already complete. You are not supposed to do that. Create an element `document.createElement( "div" )` and set the `innerText()` and then append it to the dom. Much like you did before the refactor.

**EDIT**

I understand that it wasn't the `document.write()` but just do clarify what I was talking about I wrote a little refactor. I also threw out the `theVar = one` since that is redundant. Also make sure to declare your variables in the right scope. Therefore I added a `var` in front of the `one`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll="+lat+","+lng+"&client_id=L2VWBKPOW45D5X3FJ3P4MJB5TGVJ4ST2J005RIVAFIWG44ND%20&client_secret=ZKDAOLHASCA31VUOGMBTAS3RFYUOMXL4IFFYPRURIDQA3QMA%20&v=20111107",

    function(data){
       var one = data.response.venues[0].name;

       var div = document.createElement( "div" );
       div.innerText( one );
       document.appendChild( div );

       window.location = "cookiestesttwo.php?var=" + one;
    });
  });
```

But if you change the location of the window. There is no point to `document.write()` or appending a new div since you leave the site anyways.

Comment: It wasn't documente.write.  as per your other suggestion, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I see - I still edited my answer to let you know what I thought.

Comment: Also I just saw you have a syntax error. when you close your function it needs to be `});` and not `)};` - I corrected it in my EDIT

Comment: `$(document).ready() {` is not proper syntax and does throw errors.

Comment: @rlemon: right! thanks - that's what I get for copy paste. :)

Comment: no worries, I didn't even notice them right away till I formatted his code for him. Your notes about the globals may be pre-mature, we're unsure if the variables are already defined in the parent scope :P

Comment: true - but given the code he pasted (no rant) I just assumed hew forgot or didn't know ... :P especially since changes location right after.

Answer (score 2):

`$(document).ready() {` is not proper syntax and does throw errors.

Furthermore there was another syntax error at the end of the function. you reversed } and )

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=" + lat + "," + lng + "&client_id=L2VWBKPOW45D5X3FJ3P4MJB5TGVJ4ST2J005RIVAFIWG44ND%20&client_secret=ZKDAOLHASCA31VUOGMBTAS3RFYUOMXL4IFFYPRURIDQA3QMA%20&v=20111107", function(data) {
        one = data.response.venues[0].name; // if one is local to this function then use VAR otherwise you'll leak it globally.
        document.write(one);
        theVar = one; // same here for the VAR keyword.
        urlString = "cookiestesttwo.php?var=" + theVar; // and here as well. NO GLOBAL LEAKS!
        window.location = urlString;
    });
});
```

I threw a few more hints in the comments.